# SparkR Error in readTypedObject(con, type) : Unsupported type for deserialization

Tags: r, apache-spark, bigdata

I just started with SparkR. I wrote a simple script, initialized Spark run the analysis and collected my output to R. When trying to stop sparkR by:

```
sparkR.stop()
```

I'm getting the following:

```
Stopping SparkR
Error in readTypedObject(con, type) : Unsupported type for deserialization
```

And it seems that Spark didn't stop, because:

```
> sc <- sparkR.init(master="local")
Re-using existing Spark Context. Please stop SparkR with sparkR.stop() or restart R to create a new Spark Context
```

Can anyone explain to me what is happening and what this error means? Thanks

Comment: Is there already more than one Spark context running? This might also be an underlying Spark "bug" or NYI feature that SparkR is able to trigger more easily due to the typical workload of SparkR applications. I think it is easier to trigger (e.g. c.f.: issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4080) when an application does a lot of work over a long period in a cluster. Probably best to try the Spark or SparkR mailing lists for help

Comment: These PRs might be useful :-) cheers sparkr.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKR-145 sparkr.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKR-177

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the SparkR backend process didn't exit correctly You can explicitly stop the SparkR backend process by listing all java processes with something like `jps` and then issuing a `kill <pid>` for the pid corresponding to SparkRBackend.
Restarting SparkR after this should fix things